# Jenkins - Periodic Reincarnation-Plug-in

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I want to use the "Periodic Reincarnation"-Plug-in to rebuild my failed jobs -
but its not working. I just checked "Enable afterbuild job reincarnation" under "Periodic Reincarnation of failed builds" in the settings and set the depth to 2. Nothing happens.

I got the newest version of it, 1.3 - jenkins is also up to date. Maybe I just missed here something, but https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Periodic+Reincarnation+Plugin says that it should work like this. Maybe it's because the newsest version is from the 17.07?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a reg ex configured in order to target groups of failed jobs? The Afterbuild instant restart also uses regular expressions when configured globally. You can also, locally, set a particular job to be restarted with a custom depth, only then the job will be restarted without a regex. Try putting .* as a reg ex and then every job that fails will be restarted until the maximal depth has been reached.